# problem with mysql function with summarise amount

Tags: mysql

```
BEGIN  
  SELECT p.amount into @amount from patient p WHERE p.auto_id like _id;
  SELECT r.amount into @receipt from receipt r WHERE r.patient_id like _id;  
  RETURN ifnull(@amount,0)-ifnull(@receipt,0); 
end
```

I have two tables one is called patient other is called receipt,
so patient has amount receipt so on ,
patient I create only one time
but ,,,the receipt I can receipt multiple times

I have two tables one is called patient other is called receipt,
so patient has amount receipt so on ,
patient i create only one time
but ,,,the receipt i can receipt multiple times

Comment: Please describe the 'problem' BTW I suspect you need to sum the receipts..

Comment: I want to subtract amount in patient that i promotion it. and receipt , what if i receipt mult times ,  and i promotion patient one time

Comment: Consider the second part of my comment? Not what you need? post sample data and desired outcome as text together with your code so far.

Comment: *`WHERE p.auto_id like _id`* LIKE is pattern-searching string operator, do not use it with numeric operands.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the total of all the receipt amounts.

```
SELECT SUM(r.amount) INTO @receipt FROM receipt r WHERE r.patient_id = _id;
```

Comment: RETURN ifnull(@amount,0)-ifnull(@receipt,0);
.   what will bee

Comment: It will be the difference between `patient.amount` and the sum of `receipt.amount`.

Comment: the return statement I write same. oky.